# Pagination example for spotify api java [spotify-web-api-java]

Tags: java, api, pagination, spotify, paging

I'm trying to create a playlist viewer and I got stuck on paging.
I want to get all the names of current users playlists.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public void getPlaylists() {
    try {
        SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder().setAccessToken(auth.getToken()).build();
        GetListOfCurrentUsersPlaylistsRequest getListOfCurrentUsersPlaylistsRequest = spotifyApi.getListOfCurrentUsersPlaylists().limit(5).offset(0).build();
        Paging<PlaylistSimplified> playlistSimplifiedPaging = getListOfCurrentUsersPlaylistsRequest.execute();
    } catch (IOException | SpotifyWebApiException e) {
        System.out.println("Erroras: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey so found out the answer myself don't know if its the correct way but it will work.

You can convert the paging object to a list :

```
List<PlaylistSimplified> playlists = Arrays.asList(playlistSimplifiedPaging.getItems());
```

And then get the info about your object normally.